# Should I learn Dojo Toolkit 1.10 or wait for 2.0?

Tags: dojo

In casting my eye around for a good, stable, javascript UI framework I've been drawn to Dojo. In particular, the Dijit set of UI components look really good, and are very good as far as accessibility is concerned.

My question is this: is it worth learning Dojo 1.10 (or at least dabbling and familiarising myself with it) before 2.0 comes out? Or is 2.0 going to be a "throw the baby out the with bath water" complete rewrite?

I could probably learn TypeScript as that would be a useful investment of my time. I'm just eager to start doing something productive in Dojo as I really think 2.0 is going to see a major resurgence of interest and it looks like something I'll want to commit to for 5, 10 years or more (hopefully!). Dojo seems to have stood the test of time well since it came out, and there's no reason to think that 2.0 won't be as stable, either (from what I can tell).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get familiar with Dojo Toolit 1.10 and later get updated with the new version.

In my opinion some concept behind Dojo will be remain very similar in the new version, for example: 
Modules/Amd, Ajax Deferreds, Promises DOM Basics.

As mention in the Ken's comment usefull source of onformation on dojo 2 can be found here:
[dojotoolkit.org/community/roadmap](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/roadmap)

Comment: Interesting article  https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/community/roadmap/ is a better source of material about 2.0.  The "2.0 migration" reference guide page you linked was written well before any parts of 2.0 were actually started, and is based more around upgrading from pre-1.7 to 1.7+ and AMD.  While I would agree that some concepts will remain similar, there will certainly be significant differences.  e.g. Dojo 2 will be written in TypeScript, `declare` will end up replaced, and widgets might end up being significantly different (still being thought through).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll have a play with 1.10 and start learning Type Script. It's the widgets that interest me in particular because I need something to replace my current UI framework, but I like the look of Dojo and its stability, which makes dojo/dijits the perfect fit.